# PostSharp OnMethodBoundaryAspect

Tags: c#, postsharp

I'm working on an aspect with postsharp 1.5 and OnMethodBoundaryAspect. 
I want my aspect have the following behavior by default:

1-If the attribute is used at class level the aspect is applied only on **PUBLIC** methods.

2-The user of the aspect can put the aspect in a private or protected method.

If I use this
[MulticastAttributeUsage(
MulticastTargets.Method, TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]
the point 1 works, but the case 2 doesn't even build becaue is incompatible.

Then I tried to use:
AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public;
in the constructor of the aspect, but doesn't work.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to implement your requirements using a SINGLE aspect class.

You may use three aspect class:

```
public abstract class MyAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
}

[MulticastAttributeUsage(..., 
      TargetMembersAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public )]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ClassLevelAspect : MyAspect
{
}

[MulticastAttributeUsage(..., 
     TargetMembersAttributes = MulticastAttributes.NonPublic )]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MethodLevelAspect : MyAspect
{
}
```

-gael

Comment: Thank you Gael, I'll follow this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to use the IAspectProvider, which provide aspects dynamically.

sample for creating such aspect, that inject different aspects for regular methods and constructors can be found in the PostSharp training about [Aspect Providers](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-12-e28093-Aspect-Providers-e28093-Part-1.aspx).

In your case you can use the sample provided and based on the 'ReflectedType.IsPublic' condition decide which aspect you wish to inject.

Comment: i know the original question was posted ~2 years ago, but i just had the same issue and found that this approach suit better for my needs.